# What's the difference in following code, when I use parentheses I get expected result but random number if I don't use the parentheses

Tags: c++

Program 1:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
int x=5;

int* xd=&x;

cout<<*xd<<endl;

(*xd)++;

cout<<*xd;

}
```

output is 5 and 6 .

Program 2:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
int x=5;

int* xd=&x;

cout<<*xd<<endl;

*xd++;

cout<<*xd;

}
```

Output is 5 and some random number rather than 6.

Comment: The second code uses `*xd++;` which is equivalent to `*(xd++);` leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if adding parentheses to an expression fixes an error, you've probably run afoul of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), a.k.a. the order of operations.

Comment: Rule of forefinger, after @JaMiT rule of thumb: if adding parentheses helps you in easily understand the code without the need to check operator precedence table, us them.

Answer (score 3):

The second code uses `*xd++;` which is equivalent to `*(xd++);` due to **operator precedence**. In other words, the postfix `operator++` has higher precedence than operator `*` used for indirection and thus by writing `*xd++` you're incrementing the pointer `xd` and then dereferencing that incremented pointer in the next statement `cout<<*xd;` which leads to undefined behavior.

```
cout<<*xd;//undefined behavior as this dereferences the incremented pointer
```

---

While the first code is well-formed because in code 1, you're first dereferencing the pointer `xd` and then incrementing that result(which is an `int`) which is totally fine.

```
(*xd)++; //valid as you've surrounded xd with parenthesis () and thus you're incrementing x instead of xd
cout<<*xd;//valid as `xd` still points to `x`
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `*xd++;` – it's _postincrement_, so the dereference is on the previous value, which is fine  (it's incorrect logic here, but not UB). The subsequent dereference in `cout<<*xd;`, is where the UB actually occurs.

Comment: @ildjarn Yup, i pasted the wrong line. Changed that line now. The explanation remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

For the first lines of code you wrote :

```cpp
int main(){

int x=5; // Here x is equal to 5

int* xd=&x; // You declare a pointer xd that points on the value of x

cout<<*xd<<endl; // The value of xd is 5.

(*xd)++; // The value of 5 +1 which is equal to 6

cout<<*xd; // Print out 6
```

As for the second code

```cpp
include using namespace std;

int main(){

int x=5; // Here x is equal to 5

int* xd=&x; // You declare a pointer xd that points on the value of x

cout<<*xd<<endl; // The value of xd is 5.

*xd++; // increment the value of the pointer address by 1

cout<<*xd; // Display a random pointer address

}
```

To understand more, you should learn about the pointer address and the pointer value
Doing (*xd)++ will increment the value of your pointer.
As for *xd ++ will increment a random value that your pointer address is pointing on.

Comment: `cout<<*xd` doesn't display pointer address, it actually displays some garbage value being pointed at by `xd`

Comment: @Batman *xd doesn't display the address, it display the value at address. which is 5 initially.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, the increment operator is being performed on the dereferenced value of xd (i.e. 5+1).

In the second example, the incprement operator is being performed on the pointer to the memory address where 5 is held, i.e. moving the pointer to after the value (which is not initialized)

Comment: Yeah that's my question .......I wonder, why would it perform the  increment operator on the address , rather than on the value at the address, Even if I am using the operator * with the pointer variable xd.

Answer (score -1):

I've Got the right answer to that Question.

Actually some operators have the same precedence, like '*' and '++'. So if they're found in the same statement the compiler deals them with associativity .
Associativity is concerned with whether the compiler performs operations starting with an operator on the right or an operator on the left.
If a group of operators has right associativity, the compiler performs the operation on the right side of the expression first, then works its way to the left. The unary operators such as * and ++ have right associativity, so the expression from the 2nd code is interpreted as *(xd++), which increments the pointer first, not what it points to. Since I've used parentheses in first code which means to deference the pointer first (*xd) ... then whatever value it holds..... increment it.

THANK YOU !

Comment: Consider adding supporting information, probably as a link. In particular https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator precedence suggests that this answer is not correct.